# Swift-Turn String into Array, but not a character array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Currently I am trying to convert this String: "['bob','joe','tom']" into a proper array: ['bob','joe','tom']
Is there a built in method to do this? If not what should I do.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Do you get that as part of an api response? Provide some additional details… especially what you’ve tried and where you’re having issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This solution

```
str.removeFirst() // Remove '[' and return 'bob','joe','tom']
str.removeLast() // Remove ']' and return 'bob','joe','tom'
str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "") // Remove ' and return bob,joe,tom
var arr = str.components(separatedBy: ",") // Split by , and convert string into array
```